# How to decrypt secured string value in powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to decrypt secured string value in powershell? I have used this code for encrypt the string value but i need to know about how to secured string value in powershell.Please help.

```
$var = Read-Host "Enter anything!" -AsSecureString
$var
$var1 = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $var
$var1
$var2 = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $var1
$var2
```

Comment: I got the solution thanks.

Comment: To decrypt the saved password:
-----------------------------------------
$vault = "C:\Scripts\pwd.txt"
$securestring = convertto-securestring -string (get-content $vault)
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securestring)
$passwsord = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)